# sample twitter oauth code in vb6 or vb.net

Tags: vb.net, api, vb6, twitter-oauth, facebook-oauth

I have been searching for sample twitter & facebook oauth code to start with, but can't seem to find any.
can anybody share some ideas

Comment: i prefer any language the anyone has. pls i made multiple post in error, help me delete the others this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680706/sample-twitter-oauth-code-in-vb6-or-vb-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several .NET libraries that do the hard work of connecting to Twitter for you.

My first recommendation is Twitterizer: http://www.twitterizer.net.  The developer of the library is very personable and his library is excellent.

My second recommendation is TwitterVB, a library that I created.  It's at http://TwitterVB.codeplex.com.

Both libraries are open-source.

Comment: Link to http://TwitterVB.codeplex.com no longer works - what are people using for ASP.NET (VB) and Twitter these days?

Answer (score 1):

Twitter Auth is discussed in this blog post

http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1924-creating-simple-twitter-client-application.aspx

Would that help?

Comment: thanks for responding i have seen that before, and tried it, but it didn't work well.

Comment: Any specifics on what didn't work? Not Connecting, no auth, can't send messages? or something else. Just curious. Also, did you have a try with the libs that DWRoelands suggested? Looks like twitterizer at least supports OAuth.

Comment: i installed the application, and can't login. i tried several times without success.